# Create key for cache

Tags: c#, linq

I want to write method which generates key for cache object.
This is my function:

```
public static string GenerateKeyForCache(string jobName, params object[] keys )
        {
            var generatedKey = keys.Aggregate(string.Empty, (current, key) => current + (key + "-"));
            return jobName + "-" + new string(generatedKey.Take(generatedKey.Length - 1).ToArray());
        }
```

This code generated key for cache, for example we have the following call:

```
CacheUtils.GenerateKeyForCache("JobName", "1","2","3");
```

The method is generated the following key: `"JobName-1-2-3"`.

What is best approach to do this?

Comment: What is the question? it is fine as is right?

Comment: What cache storage? How much is cached? What would happen on collision?

Comment: @MichaelOverhorst: I want to hear how other people do it.

Comment: @alexn: I'm using the `MemoryCache`.

Comment: @user1260827 I voted to close this question. A better place for questions like this is http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just use [String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string_members%28v=vs.90%29) methods?

```
public static string GenerateKeyForCache(string jobName, params string[] keys)
{
    return String.Format("{0}-{1}", jobName, String.Join("-", keys));
}
```

No need for `Aggreagte` or `Take`...

keep it simple

Comment: Yes, it's mroe simple. Thanks.